# Trying to understand the behavior of SED and regex

Tags: regex, sed

I've been trying to teach myself SED and regex. Everything I've done so far has worked well however I've found a snag I can't seem to get around. Let's say I run the following:

```
echo John is here | sed 's/[a-z]*/(&)/'
```

I would think the regex would find the first instance of lowercase letters...in the above "ohn" from John and then wrap it in parenthesis.

Something like J(ohn) is here.

However, what I end up with is.

()John was here.

I'm just trying to understand why this isn't working the way I think it should. What have I omitted or done wrong?

Maybe it has something to do with regex itself? I guess I should state that I'm running this on Ubuntu through the windows subsystem.

Comment: `*` matches 0 or more chars. The match happens before the first non-matching char, and replacement occurs once since no `g` flag is used. You want `sed 's/[a-z]\+/(&)/'` or `sed 's/[a-z][a-z]*/(&)/'`

Comment: Ahh, thanks Wiktor.

Comment: also be aware that `a-z` doesn't necessarily match all or only lower case letters, it just depends on your locale setting. To be sure to match all lower case letters use the character class `[[:lower:]]`.